# How can I get this timestamp format using Pythons strftime()?

Tags: python

How can I achieve this format '2021-05-18T00:00:00.000+00:00' using `strftime()`?

I stopped at `strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')` and can`t find the rest of the characters.

Comment: If the timestamp has a timezone, the timezone modifier is `%z`.  That format is the ISO 8601 format; you can use `dt.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')` to get this format.

Comment: What's your input timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it using *only* `datetime.datetime.strftime()`. The format spec doesn't provide everything you need. You have: year, month, day, hour, minute and second. You need: millisecond and offset.

```py
import datetime
time_str = "2021-05-18T00:00:00.000+00:00"
ts = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(time_str)
a = ts.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
milliseconds = round(ts.microsecond/1000)
offset = ts.utcoffset()
offset_hours, remainder = divmod(offset.seconds, 3600)
offset_minutes = round(remainder / 60)
offset_str = f"{offset_hours:02}:{offset_minutes:02}"
print(f"{a}.{milliseconds:03}+{offset_str}")
```

```
2021-05-18T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

If you're willing to accept that `datetime.datetime.isoformat()` produces very similar output, with exception to the decimal seconds, you can use it and it's much more robust, and simpler. If you can't, I urge you to determine if this is an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and you're asking about a presupposed solution rather than the actual problem.